# PHP + MySQL: File reading limit and connection error

Tags: php, mysql, file, caching

I'm having problem with query caching in files. I have a code which is trying to get file with serialized query result and if file is not found, or older then one day then I'm trying to connect to DB and get it remotely. Code looks like this:

```
    // Getting cache file function
    $cur_time = @time();
    $time_modified = @filemtime($file_path);
    if ($cur_time > ($time_modified + $cache_period_hours))
        return NULL;
    else
        return unserialize(file_get_contents($file_path));

    //If NULL is returned get result remotely;

    if($result === NULL){
       if (!db::connect("base", "192.168.1.111", "root", "password"))
             die("Database error. Can not connect to database.");

        //Execute query, write to file serialized result
    }
```

When I have huge traffic I get this error:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0.
```

But I don't know why the script is even trying to connect to database when I have fresh cached file. Is there a limit on how many users can read same file at same time? Also is there any way to prevent this MySQL error?

Comment: If `$cache_period_hours` is in hours, you need to multiply it by `3600`, since `$cur_time` and `$time_modified` are in seconds.

Comment: there's no way the `if($result` could ever be reached, since your `if ($cur_time)` stuff calls `return` in both code paths. plus, `$result` is never set in your code, so it'll always be null.

Comment: @MarcB I don't think the two codes are in the same path. I think the first code block is in a function that's called with `$result = getCachedData()`, and the second code block is after that assignment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371831/mysql-crashing-on-ubuntu-server-reading-authorization-packet regarding the MySQL error

Comment: Don't know your code structure, but maybe a clearstatcache() before filemtime could do it.

Comment: Sorry for posting confusing code. @Barmar you're right. As I said -Everything works fine with cache when I don't have much traffic but on traffic peak I get that error.
btw. (time is multiplied with 3600 and everything works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
if ($cur_time > ($time_modified + $cache_period_hours*3600))
```

This will convert `$cache_period_hours` to seconds, to match the units of the other variables.

Comment: As I said above in my comment I already did that. It's not problem in caching function. Caching works perfectly on low traffic.

Comment: I thought your comment meant that this was what you needed to solve the problem. So I turned my comment into an answer.

Comment: If you're having a problem connecting to the database in high traffic, you need to adjust the database server settings. See the question I linked to above.